# Erro no gráfico de linha no R

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

Estou tentando fazer um gráfico de linha por ano da taxa de incidencia de tuberculose, mas o gráfico não sai com a linha.

meu dados são:

```
Ano <- c(2020, 2021, 2022, 2023)
Casos <- c(162, 199, 184,159)
Pop <- c(176.000, 177.850, 177.850, 166.450)
Taxa <- c(91.74, 112.00, 115.00, 120.00)
```

Utilizei o seguinte código:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

dados%>%
  group_by(ano, Taxa) %>%
  summarise() %>%
  ggplot() +
  labs(y = "Taxa de incidência por 100 mil hab.", x = "Ano do diagnóstico") + 
  geom_line(aes(x = ano, y = TaxaiNC)) +
  geom_point(aes(x = ano, y = TaxaiNC)) +
  tema
```

Aparece a seguinte mensagem: `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?

Resultado:

[image: gráfico]

Ele plota os dados, mas não a linha. Também queria alterar a escola do eixo y.

Answer (score -1):

O código complica o que é simples. Não é necessário calcular estatísticas agregadas portanto não é necessário chamar `group_by` e `summarise`. Aliás, no código da pergunta o `summarise` está vazio, sem argumentos.

A função que deve chamar é o `mutate`, para calcular a taxa de casos por **mil** habitantes.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(dplyr)
  library(ggplot2)
})

Ano <- c(2020, 2021, 2022, 2023)
Casos <- c(162, 199, 184,159)
Pop <- c(176.000, 177.850, 177.850, 166.450)
Taxa <- c(91.74, 112.00, 115.00, 120.00)
dados <- data.frame(Ano, Casos, Pop, Taxa)

dados %>%
  mutate(TaxaiNC = Casos/Pop) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Ano, y = TaxaiNC)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  labs(y = "Taxa de incidência por mil hab.", x = "Ano do diagnóstico") +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-11-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

Para mudar a escala do eixo dos y, basta multiplicar a população por mil, uma vez que nos dados a escala é o milhar de habitantes. Agora terá a taxa de incidência por **cem mil** habitantes.

```r
dados %>%
  mutate(Pop = 1000*Pop, TaxaiNC = Casos/Pop) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Ano, y = TaxaiNC)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  labs(y = "Taxa de incidência por 100 mil hab.", x = "Ano do diagnóstico") +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-11-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

É mais simples dividir por 1000,

```
mutate(TaxaiNC = Casos/Pop/1000)
```

mas o código acima talvez seja mais fácil de perceber.